# LINQ To SQL и Access и ошибка при SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, .net, access, linq, linq2sql

Создал новый LinqToSQL класс и создал руками класс-сущности в редакторе, так как для СУБД Access автогенерация не поддерживается.

В коде создаю Context и в конструктор передаю OleDbConnection.

Все прекрасно извлекается, но при попытке вызвать SubmitChanges() для сохранения изменений вылетает ошибка:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: Row not found or changed.

Подскажите, в чем может быть косяк?

Типы сопоставил правильно, первичный ключ присутствует.

Пример кода:

```
         using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(connection))
        {
            var t = db.TestTables.Where(x => x.TestTable_id >= 52121).ToList();
            foreach (var val in t)
            {
                if (val.TestTable_id == 52121)
                {
                    val.Path = "fff";

                }
            }
             db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Классы-сущности:

```
    #pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Test
{
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System;


    public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {

        private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void InsertTestTable(TestTable instance);
    partial void UpdateTestTable(TestTable instance);
    partial void DeleteTestTable(TestTable instance);
    #endregion

        public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<TestTable> TestTables
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<TestTable>();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="")]
    public partial class TestTable : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private int _Image_id;

        private string _FaceImagePath;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnTestTable_idChanging(int value);
    partial void OnTestTable_idChanged();
    partial void OnPathChanging(string value);
    partial void OnPathChanged();
    #endregion

        public TestTable()
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Image_id", DbType="INT", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
        public int TestTable_id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Image_id;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Image_id != value))
                {
                    this.OnTestTable_idChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Image_id = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("TestTable_id");
                    this.OnTestTable_idChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_FaceImagePath", DbType="VARCHAR(255)", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                return this._FaceImagePath;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._FaceImagePath != value))
                {
                    this.OnPathChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._FaceImagePath = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Path");
                    this.OnPathChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Структура таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>      at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\iluxa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\LINQToSQLTest\Test\Program.cs:line 30
>      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: LINQ2SQL нормально работает только с MS SQL Server

Comment: @kmv откуда информация?

Comment: Автор, приведите пример неработающего кода. Желательно, чтобы там не был ничего лишнего.

Comment: такое исключение часто падает, когда данные были изменены вне Вашей программы. Думаю, если Вы выгрузите объект в память, к примеру методом **ToList** - то проблема уйдет. Также есть вероятность, что объект очень большой, который Вы меняете, но это маловероятно. Выгружайте в память и тогда не будет прямой зависимости от данных в базе - тогда будете работать с копией в переменной.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, привел.

Comment: @iluxa1810 трассировку стека еще приведите

Comment: @PavelMayorov, кинул.

Comment: @iluxa1810 у контекста linq2sql где-то есть свойство, позволяющее получить все конфликты, оно заполняется при сохранении. Посмотрите что там.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ChangeConflicts ? Я взял код обработки ошибки отсюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.changeconflicts(v=vs.110).aspx и получил, что он произошел на ID 52121

Comment: @iluxa1810 это было ожидаемо :) Посмотрите другие доступные свойства. К примеру, `MemberConflicts`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там вообще 0 элементов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а методы обновления/вставки/удаления, не нужно заранее прописывать или это должно на ходу сгенерироваться? Просто, не знаю какие нюансы при работе с Access...

Comment: @PavelMayorov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194528/linq-asp-net-page-against-ms-access

Comment: @kmv, я правильно понял, что через LINQ to SQL я могу только считать данные, но не обновить?